# argument error, :erlang.apply(#Function<xx in Mod.client/1>, :t, [])

Tags: elixir, metaprogramming

I have the following:

```
defmodule ApiWeb.Helpers.Oapi do
  import Plug.Conn
  use Tesla, only: ~w(get)a
  require Logger

  plug Tesla.Middleware.BaseUrl, "example.com"

  def client(conn) do
    Tesla.build_client [
      {Tesla.Middleware.Headers, %{"Authorization" => get_req_header(conn, "authorization") }}
    ]
  end
```

elsewhere I call:

```
client = Oapi.client(conn)
```

When I print `client` I get the above error, implicating it is a function. But if I look at the source code for Tesla.build_client it looks as if it returns a struct:

```
defmacro build_client(pre, post \\ []) do
  quote do
    %Tesla.Client{
      pre:  Tesla.prepare(__MODULE__, unquote(pre)),
      post: Tesla.prepare(__MODULE__, unquote(post))
    }
  end
end
```

Where Tesla.Client is defined as follows:

```
defmodule Tesla.Client do
  @type t :: %__MODULE__{
            fun:  (Tesla.Env.t, Tesla.Env.stack -> Tesla.Env.t),
            pre:  Tesla.Env.stack,
            post: Tesla.Env.stack
  }
  defstruct fun: nil,
            pre: [],
            post: []
end
```

This has to be some meta programming magic, but I have trouble understanding it.

Edit: what I'm actually trying to do is inspecting the `client` before the `get` call, so I can check the url, header etc.

Full stacktrace:

```
[error] #PID<0.522.0> running ApiWeb.Endpoint terminated
Server: localhost:4000 (http)
Request: GET /api/test
** (exit) an exception was raised:
    ** (ArgumentError) argument error
        :erlang.apply(#Function<0.84960178/2 in ApiWeb.Helpers.Oapi.client/1>, :t, [])
        (api_web) lib/helpers/oapi.ex:27: ApiWeb.Helpers.Oapi.users_hosted_vms/2
        (api_web) lib/plugs/subject.ex:80: ApiWeb.Plugs.Subject.load_from_oapi/2
        (api_web) lib/plugs/subject.ex:40: anonymous fn/2 in ApiWeb.Plugs.Subject.get_uid_from_cache/2
        (cachex) lib/cachex/util.ex:77: Cachex.Util.get_fallback/4
        (cachex) lib/cachex/actions/get.ex:42: Cachex.Actions.Get.handle_record/4
        (cachex) lib/cachex/actions/get.ex:28: Cachex.Actions.Get.execute/3
        (api_web) lib/plugs/subject.ex:37: ApiWeb.Plugs.Subject.get_uid_from_cache/2
        (api_web) lib/api_web/router.ex:16: ApiWeb.Router.api/2
        (api_web) lib/api_web/router.ex:1: anonymous fn/1 in ApiWeb.Router.__match_route__/4
        (phoenix) lib/phoenix/router.ex:273: Phoenix.Router.__call__/1
        (api_web) lib/api_web/endpoint.ex:1: ApiWeb.Endpoint.plug_builder_call/2
        (api_web) lib/plug/debugger.ex:99: ApiWeb.Endpoint."call (overridable 3)"/2
        (api_web) lib/api_web/endpoint.ex:1: ApiWeb.Endpoint.call/2
        (plug) lib/plug/adapters/cowboy/handler.ex:15: Plug.Adapters.Cowboy.Handler.upgrade/4
        (cowboy) /Users/raarts/work/company/api-elixir/api/deps/cowboy/src/cowboy_protocol.erl:442: :cowboy_protocol.execute/4
```

Here's the function that generated the error:

```
def users_hosted_vms(client, uid) do
  url = "/getuser?userID=" <> uid
  if (config(:api_web)[:env] != :prod) do 
    IO.inspect client.t()
    Logger.warn("ACTUAL REQUEST TO #{inspect(client.t)}} on endpoint #{url}")
  end 
  get(client, url)
end
```

Comment: You only get the error when you "print" `client`? How are you printing it? I don't think any print function can throw this kind of error.

Comment: Sorry, I added that after the fact. IO.inspect.

Comment: Please post the complete error message including the stacktrace.

Comment: I added it to the question

Comment: When I removed the `.t()` the stacktrace went away, but now IO.inspect prints `#Function<0.117667995/2 in ApiWeb.Helpers.Oapi.client/1>` . That's   what started this hunt.

Comment: I don't know much about Tesla, but I don't think this is gonna work like this. `build_client` is a macro but the argument you're passing to it is only known at runtime. Your main error is caused by calling `.t()`. `client` is a function that takes 2 arguments, so the way to call it is `client.(arg1, arg2)`.

Comment: SO suddenly offered me the option to go to chat, which was new to me. Sorry if you don't appreciate it, but I thought I just tried. My actual question was, turns out, why does it print as a function, while the build_client returns a struct?

Comment: I looked at the README of Tesla and indeed your code looks correct and that function should return a struct. Can you try reproducing this problem in a new file (or `iex`) and post the complete code?